# No overload matches this call on simple react app

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and running below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App greeting="Welcome to React" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I run this code system throwing error saying that 'No overload matches this call on simple react app' on the line `<App greeting="Welcome to React />` and `Property 'greeting' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)` error on the line `<h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>`.

Can you please help on what is the mistake that I am doing here?

Comment: That's a tsx error, you have to define the type of the prop greeting

Comment: @Rajesh, as sasal mentioned this is a type script error, As your file extension will be .tsx. So in order to resolve i have added a solution kindly check and let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related to tsx,

> In tsx, type of props (not to be confused with propTypes) need to be
> explicitly defined when extending React.Component, otherwise the type
> {} will be assumed as the props.

So your code can be rewritten as

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component<{ greeting: string }> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App greeting="Welcome to React" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/no-overload-matches-etk9r)

Answer (score 1):

For this error, you have to define an interface for the props like below.

```
interface AppConfig {
  greeting: string;
}

export default class App extends Component<AppConfig> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-meadow-54uie?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

When ever you pass props pass it always from a component to another component. As in this case there is no component. This is not a component.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App greeting="Welcome to React" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Do it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Heading greeting="Welcome to React" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now fetch the props like this:

```
class Heading extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```